# Jetpack Compose - Access specific item in row/grid

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I change the composables within a row?

For example if I had something like this:

```
@Composable
fun WordGrid() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
        MyCard("")  basically a card with Text
        MyCard("")
        MyCard("")
    }
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
        MyCard("")
        MyCard("")
        MyCard("")
   
    }
}

fun MyCard(text: String?) {
Card() {
    Text(
        text = text?: ""
        )
    }
}
```

and two buttons:

```
Button "A" and Button "B"
```

each time a button is clicked a card should get the text from the button, and then the next card and then the last.

clicking buttons A B A B would give you:

```
@Composable
fun WordGrid() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
        MyCard("A")  basically a card with Text
        MyCard("B")
        MyCard("A")
    }
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
        MyCard("B")
        MyCard("")
        MyCard("")
   
    }
}
```

How do you go about something like this unidirectionally? With XML you would be able to access the card.id directly from the ViewModel, here they have no id.

Is the only way to check if a button has been pressed and then create a state for that, pass this to the row and run through a for loop?

This seems much more complicated than having a simple id to grab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Compose you can't access views by ID. The only way is to manipulate the state which is used to build it.

I suggest you start with [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles of when you need to use state in compose. You can continue deepening your knowledge with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).

In your case you can create a mutable state list of strings, build your views based on this list and update it using the buttons by index.

Here's a basic example of what you're trying to do:

```
val cards = remember { List(6) { "" }.toMutableStateList() }
var editingIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
Column {
    Row {
        val editButton = @Composable { text: String ->
            Button({
                cards[editingIndex] = text
                editingIndex += 1
            }) {
                Text(text)
            }
        }
        editButton("A")
        editButton("B")
    }
    cards.chunked(cards.count() / 2).forEach { rowCards ->
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
            rowCards.forEach {
                MyCard(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: trying this code out though, the buttons themselves don't seem to do anything. the cards are never changed.

Comment: @JoePleavin I've just created an empty project in Android Studio, replaced `Greeting` view with this one and it works as expected. Have no idea why it might not work. Try to do the same - run this code in a new Compose project. If this still won't work, upload this project to GitHub for me to check out.

Comment: I tried exactly that, you can log 'it' and get the letters out perfectly the problem is is that the cards themselves don't seem to be re-composed meaning you are stuck with an empty row of cards no matter what. My project so far is here:  github.com/pleavinseven/WordlCompose

Comment: @JoePleavin I haven't found any of my code in your repository. I expect to see how my code doesn't work for you. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bY7lzimKLM) is how it works for me

Comment: The repository is updated now to show your code being used inside.

Comment: @JoePleavin you're saying that my code doesn't work but you're showing me how you're trying to adopt it. The state works fine in your repo, the letters are just being cut because of your modifiers. If you remove [these](https://github.com/pleavinseven/WordlCompose/blob/83f8dc9160876836d2d3677331692794410ac903/app/src/main/java/com/example/wordlesixcompose/ui/GameScreen.kt#L157-L158) two lines you'll see that it works. I'm not gonna sort out how to build the UI you're looking for, as this is our of scope in this question.